# Deriving the distance of closest approach between ellipsoid and line (prev. "equation of a 3-dimensional line in spherical coordinates")

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates

Currently trying to solve a problem of calculating the smallest distance between a given ellipsoid centered on the coordinate system starting point and a given line (located... somewhere).
After chasing a few promising but non-functional methods I have settled on trying to use spherical coordintates - to determine the formula for said distance by determining the formula of the distance of the ellipsoid from the center and doing the same for the line, consequently subtracting the two, and using gradient descent on the resulting function to approach a minimum (hopefully the global one).
However, while that makes the ellipsoid calculations easy, I have found no consise way of determining a line in spherical coordinates in equation form. I have found the old questions on similar topics proposing use of Euler angles and the like, but that does not seem to be the solution (possibly because I haven't managed to appreciate it). So, asking here - is there any way to derive an equation for a line in 3-dimensional space in spherical coordinates?
Alternate methods for the task at hand are appreciated too - for the record, my previous lead was using a cyllindrical coordinate system with the line as its X axis, but the resulting formula for the ellipsoid turned out to be bogus.

Edit: may have figured out a solution for the bigger problem that does not rely on the spherical equation - see my own answer to the question. Title changed accordingly.

Edit 2: Scratch that. Fell into the same trap again; that solution is not going to work.

Comment: I'll rewrite the answer later today; have errands to attend to right now. Apologies for the mess, I'm honestly ashamed I generated that garbage yesterday. My brain must've been malfunctioning.. but that's pretty usual for me.)

Comment: No worries, again, take your time - currently trying things on my end as well.

Comment: First, I realized I've made this particular error before, and forgot to erase my garbage notes. (I have a directory for math topics, one subdir per topic, I put my musings into.) Second, ellipsoids are a bit difficult, and there are lots of interesting papers written on the subject; however, they're a bit theoretical in my opinion. Third, I am investigating an approach where the *line* is transformed to $x$ axis, so we only need to investigate the distance between a point and the ellipsoid projected to $yz$ plane. We do still need to find the extremum ellipse on $yz$ plane, though.

Comment: Yes, rotating the line parallel to an axis (I chose $z$ for simplicity), then translating the ellipsoid to origin, definitely yields an answer. (As long as you can find the minimum 2D distance between a point and an ellipse, which I omitted from my already long answer.) Note that the ellipse is the *projection* of the ellipsoid to the $xy$ plane (seems like *"shadow"* is used in the literature). Hopefully the summary explains the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

Rotate the ellipsoid and the line so that the line is parallel to the $z$ axis. Translate the line so that the ellipsoid is centered at origin.

Projecting the ellipsoid to the $xy$ plane yields an ellipse. This 2D ellipse is at the same distance from the line (the 2D point where the line projects to the $xy$ plane), as the original ellipsoid is from the original line.

I shall assume the methods for finding the 2D distance between a point and an ellipse are known.

---

Let's say you have an ellipsoid with semi-axis vectors
$$\vec{p}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{p}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{p}_3 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \\ z_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$$where the three semi-axis vectors are perpendicular ($\vec{p}_1 \perp \vec{p}_2$, $\vec{p}_1 \perp \vec{p}_3$, and $\vec{p}_2 \perp \vec{p}_3$; i.e. $\vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{p}_2 = 0$, $\vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{p}_3 = 0$, and $\vec{p}_2 \cdot \vec{p}_3 = 0$).
You also have a line (or line segment),
$$\vec{p}(t) = \vec{p}_0 + t \vec{p}_\Delta$$
where
$$\vec{p}_0 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{p}_\Delta = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_\Delta \\ y_\Delta \\ z_\Delta \end{matrix} \right ], \quad 0 \le t \le 1$$
First, construct a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ which rotates the line parallel to the $z$ axis. Let
$$\mathbf{R} = \left [ \begin{matrix} r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\ r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} \\ r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} \hat{r}_1 \\ \hat{r}_2 \\ \hat{r}_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$$where $\hat{r}_1$, $\hat{r}_2$, and $\hat{r}_3$ are row vectors. The last one corresponds to the direction of the line:
$$\hat{r}_3 = \left [ \begin{matrix} r_{31} \\ r_{32} \\ r_{33} \end{matrix} \right ] = \frac{\vec{p}_\Delta}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_\Delta\right\rVert} = \frac{\vec{p}_\Delta}{\sqrt{\vec{p}_\Delta \cdot \vec{p}_\Delta}}$$
The two other vectors need to be perpendicular to the line, and to each other. You can for example construct three temporary vectors,
$$\vec{t}_1 = \frac{\vec{p}_1 \times \hat{r}_3}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_1\right\rVert}, \quad
\vec{t}_2 = \frac{\vec{p}_2 \times \hat{r}_3}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_2\right\rVert}, \quad
\vec{t}_3 = \frac{\vec{p}_3 \times \hat{r}_3}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_3\right\rVert}$$
and pick two longest ones, normalizing them to unit length. (Because vector cross product is perpendicular to both vectors, and the three semi-axis vectors are perpendicular to each other, at least two of the temporary unit vectors have positive length.)

From this point on, $\vec{p}_1$, $\vec{p}_2$, and $\vec{p}_3$ are assumed to be the ellipsoid semi-axis vectors, rotated by $\mathbf{R}$ so that $\vec{p}_\Delta$ is parallel to the $z$ axis ($x_\Delta = y_\Delta = 0$, $z_\Delta \gt 0$), with the center of the ellipsoid at origin.

---

Let
$$\vec{p} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\mathbf{A} = \left [ \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix} \right ]$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
a_{11} &= \frac{x_1^2}{(x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2)^2} + \frac{x_2^2}{(x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2)^2} + \frac{x_3^2}{(x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2)^2} \\
a_{22} &= \frac{y_1^2}{(x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2)^2} + \frac{y_2^2}{(x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2)^2} + \frac{y_3^2}{(x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2)^2} \\
a_{33} &= \frac{z_1^2}{(x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2)^2} + \frac{z_2^2}{(x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2)^2} + \frac{z_3^2}{(x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2)^2} \\
a_{12} = a_{21} &= \frac{x_1 y_1}{(x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2)^2} + \frac{x_2 y_2}{(x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2)^2} + \frac{x_3 y_3}{(x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2)^2} \\
a_{13} = a_{31} &= \frac{x_1 z_1}{(x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2)^2} + \frac{x_2 z_2}{(x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2)^2} + \frac{x_3 z_3}{(x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2)^2} \\
a_{23} = a_{32} &= \frac{y_1 z_1}{(x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2)^2} + \frac{y_2 z_2}{(x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2)^2} + \frac{y_3 z_3}{(x_3^2 + y_3^2 + z_3^2)^2} \\
\end{aligned}$$
The ellipsoid can now be described in matrix form using
$$\vec{p}^T \mathbf{M} \vec{p} - 1 = 0 \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
If we project the ellipsoid to the $xy$ plane, the resulting curve (*shadow*) is also an ellipse. The distance between this ellipse and point $(x_0, y_0)$ is the minimum distance between the original ellipsoid and the original line.

The $z$ component of the gradient of the ellipsoid is zero at the projected ellipsoid:
$$\frac{d}{d\,z} \left ( \vec{p}^T \mathbf{M} \vec{p} - 1 \right ) = 0 \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
Solving $\eqref{NA2}$ for $z$ yields
$$z = -\frac{(a_{13} + a_{31}) x + (a_{23} + a_{32}) y}{a_{33}} \tag{3}\label{NA3}$$
Substituting $\eqref{NA3}$ into $\eqref{NA1}$ gives us the equation for the projected ellipse on the $xy$ plane,
$$x^2 \left ( a_{11} - \frac{(a_{13} + a_{31})^2}{4 a_{33}} \right ) +
x y \left ( a_{12} + a_{21} - \frac{(a_{13} + a_{31})(a_{23} + a_{32})}{2 a_{33}} \right ) +
y^2 \left ( a_{22} - \frac{(a_{23} + a_{32})^2}{4 a_{33}} \right ) - 1 = 0 \tag{4a}\label{NA4a}$$
That is, if we use
$$\begin{aligned}
C_1 &= a_{11} - \frac{(a_{13} + a_{31})^2}{4 a_{33}} \\
C_2 &= a_{12} + a_{21} - \frac{(a_{13} + a_{31})(a_{23} + a_{32})}{2 a_{33}} \\
C_3 &= a_{22} - \frac{(a_{23} + a_{32})^2}{4 a_{33}} \end{aligned}$$
the equation of the projected ellipse is
$$C_1 x^2 + C_2 x y + C_3 y^2 - 1 = 0 \tag{4}\label{NA4}$$

---

Note that solving $\eqref{NA4}$ for $x$ yields
$$x = - y \frac{C_2}{2 C_1} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ y^2 ( C_2^2 - 4 C_1 C_3 ) + 4 C_1}}{2 C_1}$$
or for $y$,
$$y = - x \frac{C_2}{2 C_3} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ x^2 ( C_2^2 - 4 C_1 C_3 ) + 4 C_3}}{2 C_3}$$
These can be used to find the axis-aligned bounding box, i.e. the ranges for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates for the ellipse, by setting their derivative to zero. That yields
$$\begin{aligned}
x_{bb} &= \frac{\pm C_2}{\sqrt{4 C_1^2 C_3 - C_1 C_2^2}} \\
y_{bb} &= \frac{\pm C_2}{\sqrt{4 C_1 C_3^2 - C_3 C_2^2}} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: @LanceRD: If you need this for a computer program (C, C++, Python), let me know: I might be able to help with a practical implementation, especially if you have already implemented the 2D case (finding the distance between a point and an arbitrary ellipse). You can contact me directly, using the address shown on my home page, linked to from my profile.  I still feel bad and ashamed for my initial, completely bogus answer..